# I have an issue in AngularJS while sending some parameter(dynamic data {{}}) to the controller

Tags: angularjs, controller

```
//Here is the HTML code
<div ng-controller="getuserById" userid="{{ques.created_by}}" >
</div>

//Here is the Controller   
obj.controller('getuserById', function ($scope, $http,$attrs) {
    console.log($attrs.userid);
    $http.get("some_url_here?attr1="+$attrs.userid)
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.user = data;
     })
    .error(function() {
        $scope.user = "error in fetching data";
     });
 });
```

From above code when I put the hard code in userid attribute then it works while in dynamic data it doesn't
So tell me how can i resolved it?

Comment: Why do you want to do that this way? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you can use ng-model instead of attribute

Comment: I just want to send the dynamic parameter to the controller, that it. @JayantPatil if I use ng-model instead of another attribute then how can I get the value in controller?

Comment: But why do you want to do that in your view code(HTML)? That is the wrong place to do logic. Which is why you have trouble doing it

Comment: Hi @LionC ! Please consider the scenario , Suppose I answered multiple question in any forum that is created by different-2 users , I want to see all answered question as-well-as the creator details , best answered and my answered , So, to get the creator information I have to call another controller and for the sake of it I need creator/user id .

Comment: @kumardippu then you either want to create an own directive for that (defining user-id as an attribute to be passed in the scope-properety of the directives DDO) or if it is always the same users and you think you do not need a directive, create an `angular.constant` containing the user(s) and injecting that into your controller

Answer (score 0):

User ng-model instead. Here is the modified code.

```
 <div ng-controller="getuserById" ng-init="userid=ques.created_by" >
 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
obj.controller('getuserById', function ($scope, $http) {

$http.get("some_url_here?attr1="+$scope.userid)
  .success(function(data){
      $scope.user = data;
   })
  .error(function() {
      $scope.user = "error in fetching data";
   });
 });
```

Comment: what does it print when you console.log(ques.created_by)?

Comment: then if ques.created_by is undefined of-course userid will also be undefined. Populate ques.created_by correctly and code will work.

Comment: But when I'm trying to inspect by element then it shows the correct value....{{ques.created_by}}

Comment: you have to initialize your userid =0 first then it will work

Answer (score 0):

//Here is the HTML

```
<div getuserbyid value="{{ques.created_by}}" > </div>
```

//Here is the Directive I used below

```
obj.directive('getuserbyid', function ($http) {
    return function (scope, element, attr) {
    attr.$observe('value', function(actual_value) {
    element.val("value = "+ actual_value);
})
console.log(attr.value);

$http.get("some_url_here?attr1="+attr.value)
    .success(function(data){
    scope.user = data;
})
.error(function() {
   scope.user = "error in fetching data";
});

}
```

});

//Above code is working fine :)